# assigning two name/value in input

Tags: php, mysql

hello on input I want to assign 2 names so that in my sql query in what data value I put in the input the n1 and n2 have the same values data stored.

```
<input name=n1 name=n2>
```

#### my sql query is like this

```
$sql="INSERT INTO database (n1 , n2) values ('$_POST[n1]','$_POST[n2]')";
```

would this possible though?

Comment: `<input name=n1 value=n1> <input name=n2 value=n2>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is not possible for same value

```
<input name="n1" type = "text">
```

php code :- store post value in variable and use it

```
$val = $_POST['n1'];  //escape your post value
$sql="INSERT INTO database (n1 , n2) values ('$val','$val')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Just concatenate it and Insert into TABLE instead of database ? database is your table name

```
$sql="INSERT INTO `table` (`n1` , `n2`) values ('".$_POST['n1']."','".$_POST['n2']."')";
```

Answer (score 0):

You may do something like this.

```
<input name="n1">
```

And then

```
$_POST['n2'] = $_POST['n1'];
```

Comment: thanks sir. but where should I put that code?